# Same desired company, with an employee that has the same last name as yours

Tags: resume

I badly need an answer right now. I am applying a job with the company that I really want. Too bad I was informed that there is a current employee there that has the same last name as mine. She's my second degree cousin, if considered. So, what are the odds? I really really want to work in that company. But the company is very very big and growing. So maybe I may be assigned to farther company branch. Is there a possibility I could get in? Please.

Comment: "Too bad I was informed that there is a current employee there that has the same last name as mine." Why is this even possibly an issue? Given the [birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem), any reasonably sized company will have people with the same surname.

Comment: "Too bad I was informed that there is a current employee there that has the same last name as mine." I suppose I must be missing a cultural context here - could you explain why this is 'bad' ?

Comment: @PhilipKendall the birthday paradox doesn't really apply when you consider this for the OP's point of view. A company with 252 employees has a 50% chance of somebody sharing their birthday with you.

Comment: I assume that this company has some sort of policy against family members working together.  If so, perhaps edit your question to add in this important piece of context.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your words. It is a problem with me because the manger asked me "Do you know her? and I said yes. And then I saw in his face a "slight-not-a-good-thing-look" And told me, the selection will be in the hands of the HR.

Comment: "We find ways" this is the tagline of the company. I hope they would consider me despite from this concern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can't tell you the odds that this will be a problem - it will depend entirely on the company's own policies regarding employing relatives of other employees. Anti-nepotism policies are in place at some companies but certainly not all - and the fact that the relationship is relatively distant may work in your favor in any case.

Honestly I wouldn't over think it - just let your application follow it's natural course and if it asked about this cousin simply state that they are your second cousin and you aren't really close (assuming that you aren't, your post makes it sound that way)

Comment: + 1 ... It's worth asking this company if the nepotism is an issue and if yes ask to see a copy of the policy, as second cousins seems to be more distant than the typical immediate relatives I've heard of in other policies.

Comment: Thank you very much! I really appreciate your answer. I really hope I could get in.

Comment: I have never heard of an Anti-nepotism policy that applied to a second cousin.

Comment: @Ramhound I've seen a couple that were broad enough to include second cousins (while that may not have been the intent) by referring only to "relatives" or "family members", whether they would have ever actually applied them in such a case I can't say as it never came up.